# Android studio run 'app', but I can't find any devices

Tags: android, adb, emulation, android-virtual-device

I've installed android studio 3.1.3 on my Mac OS.
I tried to run 'app', but can't find any devices in 'Select Deployment target' window.

I created emulator and connected real device.
I can't find both.

[image]

[image]

$ ./adb devices

List of devices attached

015d49069947fa01    unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate the ADV Device,and use cold boot after creation.Then try running it.